Calculating Daily Returns for a Zero Net Investment Portfolio
I'm trying to create a zero net investment portfolio in an equally weighted manner using daily holding period returns for stocks. Here is my setup:

Day 1:
Long: Stocks A, B, C
Short: Stock D

Day 2:
Long: Stock D
Short: Stocks B, C


I want to calculate the daily returns for the long, short, and long-short (LS) positions.

Day 1 Calculations:

$R_{long}=R_{A}*1/3+R_{B}*1/3+R_{C}*1/3$
$R_{short}=-R_{D}$
$R_{LS} = R_{long}+R_{short}$

Day 2 Calculations:

$R_{long} = R_{D}$
$R_{short} = -R_{B}*1/2 + R_{C}*1/2$
$R_{LS} = R_{long}+R_{short}$
Is this calculation correct
I think we're investing one dollar on each side (long and short). What is the total investment amount now? Are there any adjustments I need to apply for this calculation? Do these newly calculated returns align (in scale) with the holding period returns?

Hi: you have to be careful that the asset values are in the correct proportion or else you won't be able to use (1/3, 1/3, 1/3) or (1/2 and 1/2). So when you take those positions, you need to specific the dollar value that was invested in each position. That determines the fractions like 1/2 or 1/3. If you provide the initial dollar values in each position,  it will be straightforward to show you whether you are doing it correctly.

I see where you're coming from, but I don't completely agree with your proposed solution. When we look at returns this way, it's like we're investing $1 in each position. Using weights like 1/2 means we're allocating half a dollar to each position. So, I'm a bit unsure about how the prices are factoring in here.

Hi: So, you are assuming that you put a dollar in each stock. Is that true for stock D also or is there 3 dollars on stock D in day 1? The calc changes depending on the amount of dollars invested in stock D.

Yes. I believe the main idea here is to keep everything on the same scale for consistency. Let's say we have a return of 0.05. This means that if we invest one dollar, it grows to 1.05 dollars. So, if we consider all positions as one dollar (including stock D on day 1), we can simply sum up the returns for each position. This way, we don't need to worry about the actual prices anymore and can base our calculations purely on the returns (considering the weights).

That makes sense. But, on day 1,  if you go long 3 stocks investing a dollar in each and you go short D where a dollar's worth was shorted, then, overall you are long 2 dollars and it's not a zero investment scenario. But maybe I still don't understand what you're saying. Could you be shorting 3 dollars worth of D ?

I see. Those weights are actually keeping everything balanced. When we invest 1/3 of a dollar in each for the long side on the first day, it adds up to one dollar in total. This matches the amount we're investing on the short side.

Okay: So let's be clear. On Day 1:  you are investing 1/3 of a dollar on each of the stocks on the long side and one dollar on the stock D short side ? What are you doing on Day 2 ? It looks like things got flipped possibly ?

On the second day, the amount is 1 dollar in D and 50 cents each in B and C. We keep each position just for one day.

Given what you stated about dollar amounts, what you wrote seems fine. On day 2, you left out the negative sign on $R_C$  but that's just a typo. Nice job.
